# Latex figure ambient: how to start the indexing of the figures from a fixed number?

Tags: indexing, latex, figure

What I am searching for, is a method to start the indexing inside the latex figure ambient from a fixed number that I choose.

Looking at the following screenshot:
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ1N6.png)
what I want is that the indexing does not start from 1, but from a specific number.

Online I found the command `\setcounter{figure}{}`, but adding it to my latex file does not change anything. As a proof here's the corresponding latex code:

```
\begin{figure*}[bth]
\renewcommand*\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}
\setcounter{figure}{7}
\subfloat[Type 1, correctly classified]
{\label{fig:7corr}
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{Figures/saliencymaps/correct/1smcorrtype1.pdf}} \quad
\subfloat[Type 2, correctly classified]
{\label{fig:8corr}
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{Figures/saliencymaps/correct/2smcorrtype2.pdf}} \quad
\subfloat[Int. type, correctly classified]
{\label{fig:10corr}
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{Figures/saliencymaps/correct/4smcorrtypeint.pdf}} \quad
\subfloat[Type 2, correctly classified]
{\label{fig:11corr}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{Figures/saliencymaps/correct/5smcorrtype2.pdf}} \quad
\subfloat[Type 2, correctly classified]
{\label{fig:12corr}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{Figures/saliencymaps/correct/6smcorrtype2.pdf}} \quad
\subfloat[Int. type, correctly classified]
{\label{fig:13corr}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{Figures/saliencymaps/correct/7smcorrtypeint.pdf}} \quad
\subfloat[Type 1, correctly classified]
{\label{fig:14corr}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{Figures/saliencymaps/correct/8smcorrtype1.pdf}} \quad
\subfloat[Type 1, correctly classified]
{\label{fig:15corr}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{Figures/saliencymaps/correct/9smcorrtype1.pdf}} \quad
\caption[Saliency maps for correctly classified spectra.]{Saliency maps for correctly classified spectra.}\label{fig:sal_maps_corr}
\end{figure*}
```

where I put `\setcounter{figure}{7}` in order to make the numbering start from 7, but the result is the one that you can seen in the above figure.

Do you have any suggestions on how to solve the problem?
Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Please make a [mre] instead of this code fragment

Answer (score 5):

Solved: the right command to use in the `\figure` environment was `\addtocounter{subfigure}{n}`, where n is the number added to the subfigure counter (in my case n=6 to have the first figure with counter (7)), in place of `\setcounter{figure}{7}`.